# Why am I getting multiple Gmail Notifications?

Tags: gmail, notifications

Ever since the 2.2 update, I'm receiving multiple Gmail notifications without accessing the Gmail app and with the setting "Notify only once" active.

I've tried a factory reset, but it still does this.

Any thoughts? *I do have my Gmail auto-popping another account, could this be it?*

Comment: Are you being notified multiple times for only a single email or notified for additional emails?

Comment: Notified for additional e-mails.  In Gmail under Notification Settings there is an option called "Notify once" and I have it checked.

Comment: Are you sure one of the emails isn't from another email client?

Comment: I have one account setup (my primary). I also only use the Gmail app. Perhaps I don't follow.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? Did you tried to lose the other account you've mentioned, to see if the issue was caused by it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like maybe you added your GMail account to the regular Mail app.  So you are probably receiving notifications from both apps.

If you are only using the "GMail" app then find the "Mail" (not "GMail") app in your app drawer and run it and see if your mail is in there too.  If it is just delete the account from there and then you should only get notifications from GMail not Mail.

Comment: I admit that I initially fell into this confusion.  I didn't realize that the gmail app is pre-installed and separate from the mail client.  The two envelope icons befuddled me for some time...

Comment: I only have my Gmail configured under the Gmail app. It has never been setup under the Mail app.

Answer (score 0):

I got a new phone and this issue seemed to resolve itself. Not sure why it was doing it before, but it's not doing it now.